# Pass Table as parameter to function

Tags: sql, t-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a temp table which contains data needed in selection, but I can't join in to main select statement because it contains too many rows, and grouping is not good enough. So I decided to use values directly from my temp table in the selection, and it works fine. But since I need to add selection from temp table 50 times as sub queries in that main selection, I was considering to move it to function, as is nicer to call a function 50 times than sub queries.
**My question is how to pass values from that table to function?** Function will be also supplied with other parameters needed for extraction exact value from that table. I know I can't pass temp table as a parameter, but what about table variable? I don't care if I use temp table or a table variable.. 
Firstly I wrote a function containing the select statement same as for temp table, and it works but too slow. So if I could pass table results to a function, it will speed up the process..

My function now look like this:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [document].[GetPersonPremium] 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @DocumentId bigint,
    @PersonId bigint,
    @PeriodId int,
    @PersonRole nvarchar(20)
)
RETURNS DECIMAL (18,2)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @premiumSum decimal (18,2)


    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
    set @premiumSum = 
        (select top 1 pt.Premium from document.Document d
        inner join document.Person p on p.DocumentCalculationLayerID = dcl.DocumentCalculationLayerID
        inner join document.PersonTasks pt on pt.PersonId = p.PersonId
        inner join document.PersonCalculationHelper pch on pch.PersonTaskId = pt.PersonTaskId
        inner join document.PersonTaskCalculationHelper ptch on ptch.PersonId = p.PersonId
        inner join document.PersonMarkTypes pmt on pmt.ConcernMarkTypeID = ptch.ConcernMarkTypeId
        where dcl.DocumentID = @DocumentId and p.PersonId = @PersonId and pch.PeriodId = @PeriodId and pmt.Name = @PersonRole)

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @premiumSum

END
```

And I would like to use it from stored procedure like this:

```
...
    Engineer = Coalesce(document.GetPersonPremium(@DocumentId, p.PersonID, 65, 'Intern'), 0.00),
...
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Could you clarify which software you're using. You've tagged both MySQL and tsql.

Comment: T-SQL is used in SQL Server and Sybase. MySql use an SQL dialect called MySql. The code you've posted looks like T-SQL.

Comment: "I can't join in to main select statement because it contains too many rows," . . . This makes no sense.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - below in SP I have a big select statement with 60+ columns and multiple joins, from which is needed to return one row per each person, and object in app that is expecting those values. That is what I called main select statement, where filtered values from temp table are needed to be combined with other data retrieved from joins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is for those who come to this page with same or similar problem.
I created a table type:

```
CREATE TYPE PremiumTableType AS TABLE
(
    PersonId bigint,
    PeriodId int,
    PersonRole nvarchar(20),
)
```

Included it in function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [document].[GetPersonPremium] 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @DocumentId bigint,
    @PersonId bigint,
    @PeriodId int,
    @PersonRole nvarchar(20),
    @PremiumTableType PremiumTableType readonly
)
RETURNS DECIMAL (18,2)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @premiumSum decimal (18,2)


    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
    set @premiumSum = (select p.Premium from @PremiumType p where p.PersonId = @PersonId and p.PeriodId = @PeriodId and p.PersonRole = @PersonRole)

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @premiumSum

END
```

In SP declared table type variable

```
Declare @PremiumTableType PremiumTableType
```

Inserted data from my temp table

```
Insert into @PremiumTableType (PersonID, PeriodId, ConcernRole, PersonPremium)
Select p.PersonID, ...
```

And called function from SP like

```
document.GetPersonPremium(@DocumentID, p.PersonID, pt.PeriodID, 'Intern', @PremiumTableType)
```